# Highlight links wwith background pane bigger than link-object without padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsbin.com/OkaC/1/edit

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
      <a class='active' href='#'>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.active {
    background:grey;
    border-radius:2px;
    padding:4px;
}
```

This is basic example of what Im trying to achieve - highlighting for ordinary links with effect that is bigger than link-element itself. Here I use padding, but it breaks consistency of visual structure of page - highlighted link is shifted relative to regular one. 
Possible solutions that I have in my mind:

- Add padding to all links.
- With JS, switch active link to absolute positioning with current coordinates.

is there any other solutions?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the solutions you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add negative margin to remove extra space around link:

```
a {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: -4px;
}
```

Other way would be to add an outline instead of padding:

```
a {
    outline: 4px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: Negative margin = Ingenious! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Add padding to this specific "ul li a", not all of the elements and this should not change the rest of your page.